# Angular 4 office Add-in taking long time in loading

Tags: angular, webpack, office-js

I am facing problem when attempting to open an Word add-in in Word 2016 MSO (16.0.7726.1049) 64-bit for Windows.

The problem is that most of the time Word get hanged or it is taking too much time in loading the app.

I am using VS 20017, ASP.Net Core, Angular 4 and Webpack running on the application.

If I am running the sample "WordWebAddIn" from Visual Studio default project That is working fine for  me.

Please help me to fix this issue.

In main.ts I using below code for Initialization:

```js
///<reference path="../typings/globals/office-js/index.d.ts" />;

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();

if (window.hasOwnProperty('Office') && window.hasOwnProperty('Word'))

 {

    Office.initialize = () => {

        console.log("Office init: bootstrapping Angular2");

        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

    }

}

else
 {

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend another approach to this. Put a spinner to the home page (which is the one you're initializing the Office.Js) and when you finish initializing it, just redirect to `#/actualurl` so you can give your users a better experience.